# Is there a way to hide images from inspection on a webpage?

Tags: image, web, download, inspect

There is a website known as ebook japan where users can buy books to read online or download to an offline reader. I noticed that in the online reader when inspecting the page that the images of the book's / comic's pages are not there, even downloading the page I do not see them.

I have a simirlar site where people can post their own comics. I would like to implement this kind of feature in my own site, I was wondering how they did it, and I haven't the foggiest where to start looking to research it.

I am currently using JS, PHP and good old fashioned HTML but am of course open to new ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference below link 
http://www.naturefocused.com/articles/image-protection.html 
I think we could make things harder for a user who want to inspect 
the images on you site, but we could not completely prevent them to do it. 
If you could provide me the link of website that could prevent images inspection,
I think I could try to find out how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, there are some good tips there but not quite what I am after. This is the site I was referencing earlier, but unfortunately you'd have to create an account and buy something to see the effect https://www.ebookjapan.jp/ebj/

Comment: Sorry @user4261590, I couldn't log in to the site ebook Japan so I couldn't check it. If we turn on Network tab of Developer Tool of the browser, could we see the scrambled images?

Comment: I think even the most complicate way couldn't prevent users take the screenshot and crop the image. So you could consider to implement watermark to ptotect your images.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way that ebook japan does it, or at least I think I have. It sends scrambled images from the server, unscrambles them as they reach the user and draws that unscrambled image on a canvas. It then discards the scrambled image, somehow tracelessly. Too advanced for me so I'm going to say that the original answer was best.